# How to add or delete a blank column in SAS System?

Tags: sas, statistics

This is my code:

```
DATA sales;

INFILE 'D:\Users\...\Desktop\Onions.dat';

INPUT VisitingTeam $ 1-20 ConcessionSales 21-24 BleacherSales 25-28

OurHits 29-31 TheirHits 32-34 OurRuns 35-37 TheirRuns 38-40;

PROC PRINT DATA = sales;

TITLE 'SAS Data Set Sales';

RUN;
```

This is the data, but the spacing may be incorrect.

```
Columbia Peaches     35  67   1 10  2  1

Plains Peanuts      210   .   2  5  0  2

Gilroy Garlics       151035  12 11  7  6

Sacramento Tomatoes 124  85  15  4  9  1
;
```

I need to add or delete a blank column at the 19th
column. Can someone help?

Comment: When you say column, are you referring to a variable? Do you want to delete a variable?

Comment: yes, column refers to variable. I just learned SAS, so I don't understand how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the dataset and then look at what the variable name is. Then do:

```
Data Want (drop=varible_name_you_are_dropping); /*This is your output dataset*/
    Set have; /*this is your dataset you have*/
Run;
```

Comment: Data Want (drop = VisitingTeam $ 19);
        Set have;
Run;

Is it like this?

Comment: @Mary `Data Want (drop = VisitingTeam); Set have; Run;`

Comment: But what about the column 19? It said specifically column 19, so it doesn't matter then?

Comment: @Mary can you show data sample with column names or numbers?

Comment: @Mary, Open your dataset...and look at your columns....then enter the name of column 19

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean...Oh ok! Nvm.

Comment: I got the same thing as the data in my question..? Do I not include "proc print data" or something?

Comment: Proc print is its own procedure. What you want to perform is a data set, which creates a whole new data table.